# Open new window from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, code-behind

I need to open a new window from code-behind on post-back if a specific radio button is selected.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI: Pop up blockers will block this window from opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run [javascript on postback](http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2008/02/05/call-javascript-function-on-postback.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use RegisterStartupScript to send a window.open script to run once the page has loaded.

However, this will cause the majority of popup blockers to get in your way.

Comment: See @BradParks answer here for a good idea on how to fool popup blockers.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this should work ;-)

Add some javascript to your radio button to open a new blank window *before* you post back. This makes it so popup blockers won't block your popup, since it's opened in response to a users click. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061385/how-to-run-a-javascript-function-before-postback-of-asp-net-button) for how to do this part.

Then, allow the postback to happen as normal and on page load, register a startup script to tell your already existing window to go to a new url.

```
 String script = "window.open('popupPage.aspx', 'myPopup')";
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "someId", script, true);
```

Note that in javascript, when you call

```
 window.open(url, 'myPopup')
```

if a window already exists with that name it'll return it instead of creating a new window... So your popup won't get blocked!

Comment: This appears to work very well.  Thanks for posting this answer long after the other answer was accepted!  You saved me a lot of grief.

Answer (score 0):

Simple sample of RegisterStartupScript:

```
RegisterStartupScript("id1", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"I'm from JavaScript.\");</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

New windows can be very sketchy, depending on the content that you need to present you might consider using an in window pop-in if you will. You will avoid pop-up blockers that way. If you can give more details we can give better answers.