# How to run a javascript function before postback of asp.net button

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net button which is runat server, there is a function handle that postback of button onclick.

How can I display a `"loading ..."` word in the page before going to the server procedure?

Answer (score 25):

Hook up [OnClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx) to some javascript function that returns true or false. The postback occurs if it returns true else it is canceled.

```
  <asp:Button id="MyButton" runat="Server" Text="Close" 
                       OnClientClick="return  PromptClose();"/>


  <script type="text/javascript">
   function PromptClose(){
       return prompt("Do you really want to close this window?");
   }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use the `onsubmit` event of your page's form. This happens before the form is submitted, and will allow you to stop submission of the form if you need by cancel bubbling. In case you need this, the last 2 lines in this example will cancel bubbling across browsers.

```
<form runat="server" onsubmit="ShowLoading()">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowLoading(e) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var img = document.createElement('img'); 
        img.src = 'http://www.oppenheim.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/ajax-loader-1.gif'; 
        div.innerHTML = "Loading...<br />";
        div.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; top: 30%; left: 40%; z-index: 5000; width: 222px; text-align: center; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #000'; 
        div.appendChild(img);
        document.body.appendChild(div); 
        
        // These 2 lines cancel form submission, so only use if needed.
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
</script>
```

The JavaScript above is just for example, however this is (in my opinion) the preferred way to do what you're looking for. It looks something like this (in the center of the screen):

> Loading...
> [image]

This will work for any element that raises a PostBack, so you don't have to manually call `ShowLoading()` on every button or form element you may have on your page. I would replace the contents of `ShowLoading()` with some real loading functionality and not just the example code I threw together.

Answer (score 3):

Look at OnClientClick, you can add a call to a js function, or inline JS there.

Or you can wire into the button with JQuery and display a modal dialog with an async callback.