# Integrating a stripe checkout with .net

Tags: javascript, c#, stripe-payments

Please I need your help, I want to integrate a stripe checkout with .net
I follow Stripe toturial step by step but the Stripe Checkout redirection doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
   <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnPay_Click" Text="S'inscrire" CssClass="btn btn-submit" id="btnPay" />
<script>
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_fuKFopc9GVK4QgRD4c3CDZng00OI6sMSyU');

    var element = document.getElementById('btnPay');

    element.addEventListener('click', function () {

        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
            // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
            // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
            sessionId: '<%= sessionid%>'
        }).then(function (result) {
            // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
            // error, display the localized error message to your customer
            // using `result.error.message`.
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my server code :

```
 protected void btnPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
            // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecretKey"];

            var options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                CustomerEmail = "customer@hotmail.com",
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> {
                                    "card",
                                },
                LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions> {
                                    new SessionLineItemOptions {
                                        Name = "TEST",
                                        Description = "my Description",
                                        Amount = 99,
                                        Currency = "eur",
                                        Quantity = 1,
                                    },
                                },
                SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
                CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
            };

            var service = new SessionService();
            Session session = service.Create(options);
```

**The redirection to Checkout doest work :( :( :(**

Comment: Are you using `clientIdMode="static"`? Are you getting JS errors?

Comment: Please see [What do you mean, "it doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: Do note your successurl is **literally** `success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`

Comment: I don't see how your server side code is ever called, it looks like you are only calling the javascript function. Look at the page source, is `sessionid` evaluating? Use the browser dev tools to trace the network requests and see what is happening.

Comment: @Crowcoder *"I don't see how your server side code is ever called"* - The button has an `OnClick`, though I agree there doesn't seem to be any "conversation" between the client and server.

Comment: @TylerRoper  Been too long since webforms. So, in that case, does the javascript have a chance to run before the postback? At the risk of being wrong again, I don't think so.

Comment: @Crowcoder IIRC, the javascript WILL run first. However, that just leaves me slightly more confused and less confident in my answer I posted...

Comment: [See this regarding running both javascript and posting back on button click.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061385/how-to-run-a-javascript-function-before-postback-of-asp-net-button)

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET

Comment: Check out the demo app and download the code to accept payments and subscriptions with all payment methods with Stripe's newest product, Payment Element --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New

Answer (score 0):

My asp.net forms is a little rusty, but I'm 90% sure I know your issue. That being said, please do read the comments and this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work so you can write better questions in the future.

NOW..

Asp.net forms likes to add their own unique ID shenanigans to objects. So even though you specified an ID for the `<asp:btn>`, it's going to have a guid or something jammed on the end of it. To confirm this, inspect the page before you actually click the button and look at what the ID value actually is in the HTML.

Adding `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your `asp:btn` is one solution, the other would be to use a css class or other query selector to actually select the `asp:btn` in your javascript code.

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, just for your information:
- When I click another time on the Button, the redirection works.

- it works well when I use checkout server code on the **page load** ! too strange.

I have followed these steps :
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
            // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecretKey"];



            var options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                CustomerEmail = "mehdizerouali@hotmail.com",
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> {
                                    "card",
                                },
                LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions> {
                                    new SessionLineItemOptions {
                                        Name = "BPENLIGNE",
                                        Description = "Formule Smart",
                                        Amount = 99,
                                        Currency = "eur",
                                        Quantity = 1,
                                    },
                                },
                SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
                CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
            };

            var service = new SessionService();
            Session session = service.Create(options);

            sessionid = session.Id;
        }
```

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET